# fopen unable to open a video file located on server

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to read a video file uploaded on server using fopen and fread in php but fopen returns `"unable to open file"`.

```
//test.php
    <?php
    $file=fopen("abc.mov","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    ?>
```

abc.mov exists in the same folder where test.php is located on the server i.e, at the same hierarchy.

I don't why it isn't able to read the file.
Please help.

Comment: What happens if you put the full path to the video file in the `fopen()` call, instead of just the name?

Comment: does the user which actually runs this script have permission to open the file?

Comment: I recommend trying an absolute path to the file rather than a relative path.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't a real problem with PHP or your file. This is most likely a problem with the permissions of the file. There are three things you can try here(probably more I don't know of). One, do this somewhere before the fopen in your script:

```
chmod("abc.mov", 0777);
```

Then echo fileperms(), just to check(take out after debug):

```
echo fileperms("abc.mov");
```

And lastly, before calling fopen, make sure that `is_readable` and `file_exists` return true:

```
if(file_exists("abc.mov") and is_readable("abc.mov")) {
    $file = fopen("abc.mov","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
}
else die("File isn't readable, or maybe doesn't even exist!");
```

Note: I would be using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` rather than fopen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx for your help. I used ur code and it returns the message File isn't readable, or maybe doesn't even exist. But I changed the file permissions from the server, then why is this msg. Can u suggest something how to change file permissions so that it becomes readable.

Comment: 0777 is *all* permissions. It should be readable, writable, and executable. Maybe you should try making a blank text file and try opening that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file access permissions to make sure you've got access to the file from PHP.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check the file permissions in php